# A switch without threshold voltage

Tags: rf

I'm working with in RF system with the same RF coil for transmitter and for  receiver.  I wait 100us microseconds while the coil is discharged to change the transmitter mode to emitter mode.

If I open the circuit quickly, the current storage disappear and I don't have to wait the 100 microseconds.

I would use the MOSFET but the Mosfet has V threshold between Source and Drain to drive. The voltage aplicate in gate I don't mind but the
minimum voltage between Source and Drain yes because my signals received are of microvolts.

The TRIAC is the same because between in the MT1 and MT2 there is a voltage threshold. Do you know some switch or discrete component that I can use? switch without voltage threshold?

[image]

I use the same circuit to transmit and receive, but in receive mode the signals are microvolts and cannot exceed the voltage threshold between Drain and Gate.

I think in an example it would be clearer. For example, if I use the Mosfet irfz44n as in the following image.

[image]

I connected the 20V battery with a 100 ohm potentiometer, the mosfet and the DC motor. If I measure the voltage between Drain and Gate when the potentiometer is practically 0 ohm, the measured voltage approaches 2v. I cannot lower this value because the datasheet shows that this is the minimum.

My question is: do you know of a Mosfet, TRIAC, SCR ... that when in drive mode, the value measure between Drain and Gate (MT1, MT2 ...) will be 0v?

Comment: Edit the title please - all caps is taken as shouting at us.

Comment: It's really unclear what it is you are asking about - what threshold do you refer to?

Comment: sorry but i'm a new in this and I don't know how work this page

Comment: the voltage drop of the mosfet itself, Gate-Source Threshold Voltage

Comment: FET VDS is related to it's on resistance. You can get FETS with under 1 milli-ohm Rdson. While you CAN get FETs with about 0V Vgson you probably need to explain your requirement better and not how you think it may be solved. || Note that turning off an inductor with current in it will not eliminate "current storage".

Comment: En las simulaciones se descarga de forma efectiva, por eso lo comento. Como crees tu que podrías descargar de forma muy rapida? he estado viendo spst de mircrorelés que creo quepodrían funcionar.